# Different tmux prefixes for different machines

Tags: tmux

Is it possible in .tmux.conf to set the prefix to different things
depending on the current hostname?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use %if/%endif, there is an example of changing the status line colour on different hosts in the manual (look under source-file). It will be the same except you will be changing the prefix option.